# Rotation & Scale in Matrices of SVG Element

Tags: javascript, matrix, svg, scale, rotational-matrices

I am helping someone solve this. We have SVG elements in `g` tag. We are using the transformation on the `g` tag and converting it into matrix.

[Here is the jsbin link.](https://jsbin.com/hayebak/edit?js,output)

We are a bit confused by the following:

- How to calculate the 'resistor', denoted by `dx` & `dy` in line 23 & 24 in the jsbin.
- Where we are going wrong with the calculations for rotate & scale using matrices.
- Is there a better way of doing this mathematically? I need to mention that the relevant person has been struggling with this for over two weeks so appreciate the help.

The relevant Js code:

```
var mouseXY; //object to store the mouse event x & y
var angle1;   //first angle before rotate
var center;   //center of the shape that we want to rotate

//this function is call when mouse down
//on the resize button

//this function bind the mouse event
//to scale the shape
function bindScaleShapeEvent(){
  mouseXYPosition(event);
  document.addEventListener("mousemove",scaleImage);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup",removeScaleImage);
}

//function to scale the shape when
//user mouse move
function scaleImage(event){

  var parent = document.getElementById("1"); //parent of shape 
  var dx = (event.pageX - mouseXY.x);
  var dy = (event.pageY - mouseXY.y);
  dx /= 80;   // 80 is the resistor value
  dy /= 80;
  var scaleX = dx;
  var scaleY = dy;
  var matrix = parent.getAttribute("transform");
  var matrixArray = matrixToArray(matrix);
    //make the new matrix of the shape
  scaleString = "matrix(" + 
    (parseFloat(matrixArray[0]) + scaleX) + " " + 
    parseFloat(matrixArray[1]) + " " + 
    parseFloat(matrixArray[2]) + " " + 
    (parseFloat(matrixArray[3]) + scaleY) + " " + 
    parseFloat(matrixArray[4]) + " " +
    parseFloat(matrixArray[5]) +")";  
  parent.setAttribute("transform", scaleString);
  mouseXYPosition(event);

}
//convert the transformation to array
function matrixToArray(matrix){
   matrix = matrix.split('(');
   matrix = matrix[1].split(')');
   matrix = matrix[0].split(' ');
  return matrix;
}

//remove eventListener from the
//shape resize button
function removeScaleImage(){
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove",scaleImage);
  document.removeEventListener("mouseup",removeScaleImage);
}



//this function is call when mouse down
//on the rotate button

//this function bind the mouse event
//to rotate the shape
function bindRotateShapeEvent(event){
  mouseXYPosition(event);
  centerXY();//store the center of the shape that we want to rotate

  var dx = (mouseXY.x) *3;
  var dy = (mouseXY.y) *3;
  angle1 = (180 * Math.atan2(dy, dx) / Math.PI); //first angle of the shape
  document.addEventListener("mousemove",rotateImage);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup",removeRotateImage);
}

//applying rotation on the shape

function rotateImage(event){

  var dx = (event.pageX - mouseXY.x);
  var dy = (event.pageY - mouseXY.y);
  var parent = document.getElementById("1");
  var angle2 = (180 * (Math.atan2(dy,dx)) / Math.PI);
  var angle = angle2 - angle1;
  var radian= 0.06 * angle;
  var cos = Math.cos(radian);
  var sin = Math.sin(radian);

  var matrix ='matrix(' +
                  (cos) +
                    ' ' + (sin) +
                    ' ' + (-sin) +
                    ' ' + (cos) +
                    ' ' + (-center.cx * cos + center.cy * sin + center.cx) +
                    ' ' + (-center.cx * sin - center.cy * cos + center.cy) +
                    ')';
parent.setAttribute("transform",matrix);
}
function removeRotateImage(){
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove",rotateImage);
  document.removeEventListener("mouseup",removeRotateImage);
}

//save the center of the shape
function centerXY(){
  var shape = document.getElementById("1");
  var bbox = shape.getBBox();
  center ={
    cx: bbox.x + (bbox.width / 2),
    cy: bbox.y + (bbox.height / 2)
  };
}
//save the move x and y
function mouseXYPosition(event){
  mouseXY = {
     x: event.pageX,
     y: event.pageY
  };
}
```

[The Jsbin link to the working demo.](https://jsbin.com/hayebak/edit?js,output)

Comment: This looks horrible, why not use the SVG DOM? https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InterfaceSVGTransform

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks. Would you please be able to give an example of how to apply that to the above transformations. Hes not clear how to apply SVGTransformList to the code.

Comment: You'd get a transform list from an element that has it.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you, we are looking into this.